# What kind of problems does Xcode address sanitizer actually warn about?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode7

Xcode 7 has a new feature called address sanitizer, which is introduced in the [release notes](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) with this short description:

> - Address sanitizer points out code that may crash at runtime even when you cannot reproduce yourself

Apart from the ironic wording, I believe what is meant here is that the address sanitizer is supposed to detect (irreproducible) problems that may result in access violations or other fatal application errors.

[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html) adds more information making it clear that this is a diagnostic tool (not a compiler feature) intended to catch memory corruption issues at debug time.

I did a few tests on my own but couldn't put together a piece of code that would trigger the address sanitizer when run. Could somebody provide me with an example? I was looking for a sample in C, but objective C would be fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is more information](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) about the address sanitizer and here's a simple test:

```
char test()
{
    char buffer[4] = { 9, 8, 7, 6 };
    unsigned index = 4;
    return buffer[index];
}
```